# Overriding bundles in Symfony2

Tags: inheritance, symfony, bundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle for my login page. I overrided it's templates, controller, routes,... using getParent() method as described here http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/override.html

Now I would like to have 2 different login pages, with different controllers, templates and routes. As you can see in the documentation, each bundle can only have one parent, so what's the best way to make 2 derivatives of a bundle?

Thanks